# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSE - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

I have a problem with my website. Images and some .js files do not finish loading. Honestly, I don’t know what could have happened, the day before the problem everything was perfect … I just woke up and it happened. I thought it might have been the “WP Super Rocket” plugin but I already tried disabling it.

In the Chrome console I get the error “Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED”.Even when I want to see the “preview” of my home page it gives me the error “HTTP ERROR 500”, this does not happen with other pages on the web. It is rare because in these two days, the page returns to normal after noon.

I know that my site is not the most optimized, I am missing a lot for that, but I have not had any errors of this kind and it was loading everything normal.
In case you have to see, my site is hosted on GoDaddy.

The website is: www.cepeban.edu.pe